# adding sorting to Google Sheets Query with embedded formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

```
=query(Sheet1!$A:$K,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,I,J,K where J IS NOT NULL format J'0%'")
```

Above is what I have right now in Google Sheets and I am trying to add a ordering function to it. I have tried

> ...J'0%', Order by B asc, C asc, D, asc

and nothing. Step two was to change everything to Col structure and try it again, but it couldn't find the Cols in the source "Sheet1" data. The formula as it is works fine, but I am having issues adding the ordering to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated–thanks!

Comment: I am so tired since it is 3 AM and the six was as follows:

"=query(Sheet1!$A:$K,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,I,J,K where J IS NOT NULL order by B asc, C asc, D asc format J'0%'")"

Answer (score 1):

`order by` must come before `format`. See [The order of the clauses must be as follows](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be no comma before ORDER BY.  Try:

`=query(Sheet1!$A:$K,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,I,J,K where J IS NOT NULL ORDER BY B, C, D ASC FORMAT J'0%'")`

Comment: Ah nice catch. Changed it.